# Overloading Kernel.require() without braking it

Tags: ruby, kernel, overloading, require

I'm trying to overload the `Kernel.require()` method to get data required to build code dependency tree. This is how I simply imagine the new require method:

```rb
def require arg
  super arg
  puts "including '#{arg}' in '#{caller_locations(1).first.path}'"
end
```

Unfortunately, I found this to be braking the `require()` invocation somewhere else in the code causing the sequence of errors.

Comment: Please don't add comments to your question unless requested. Comments are for people needing clarification from you; Your response should be to add additional information to your question to clarify the question, as if that had been there all along, without using "edit" or "update" type tags as we can see what changed and when if we need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original implementation of [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) returns `true` or `false`. Your new `require` method does not return that value anymore instead it always returns `nil` (the response from the `p` method).

I can imagine that in some cases it makes sense to have a condition in your code and define constants depending on the response of the `require`.

You can probably fix the issue by swapping the lines in your method:

```
def require(name)
  puts "requiring '#{name}' in '#{caller_locations(1).first.path}'"
  super
end
```

Comment: The `p` method, returns a string, `puts` return a `nil`, but you help me a lot. Thank you!